# Errors were found when compiling the workflow in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-2013, publish

I've searched and found a couple of questions which are similar, but the advanced part is different.

When I publish any workflow on Sharepoint 2013, selecting the 2013 option not a 2010 workflow (the 2010 works fine), I get this error:

> Errors were found when compiling the workflow. The workflow files were
>   saved but cannot be run

I click in the advanced button and get

> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Aún no se han capturado las
>   direcciones de esta aplicación. (in english is something like **"Still
>   have not caught addresses this application."**)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPConnectedServiceApplication.get_ApplicationAddresses()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPServiceLoadBalancer.d__0.MoveNext()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoundRobinServiceLoadBalancer.GetEndpoints(IEnumerable`1
>   applicationAddresses)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoundRobinServiceLoadBalancer.BeginOperation() 
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.S

I've tried re-registering the workflow service, checking if the app management service is running (was running on 1 server, started on the second server and still not working) and restarted the servers, but none of these actions has worked.

What can be happening?

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved the problem, I did uninstall the App Management Service and it's proxy and reinstalled it again. After that, the 2013 workflows can be published without a problem.

David